# C# Form is displaying an extra object

Tags: c#, forms, oop, combobox, polymorphism

So I have a parent class called SalesRep and a child class called SeniorSalesRep. I have got it so it displays both classes polymorphically to a listbox. The issue I'm having is that I have a combo box that gives the user the choice of displaying a report of the objects in the SalesRep class which should also display the SeniorSalesRep objects and if it's selected just SeniorSalesRep it only shows SeniorSales Rep objects. However, when I'm implementing this it creates an extra object called object which displays only SalesRepObjects and not SeniorSalesRep objects. How can I get rid of that extra object in my combo box?

```
 public void LoadTypeComboBox()
    {
        List<string> salesRepTypes = new List<string>();
        

        foreach (SalesRep thisSalesRep in allSalesReps)
        {
            string s = thisSalesRep.GetType().Name;
            string baseType = thisSalesRep.GetType().BaseType.Name;

            if (!salesRepTypes.Contains(s))
            {
                salesRepTypes.Add(s);
            }

            if (!salesRepTypes.Contains(baseType))
            {
                salesRepTypes.Add(baseType);
            }
        }

        cboObjectType.DataSource = salesRepTypes;
    }

    private void cboObjectType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        lstSalesReps.DataSource = null;
        lstSalesReps.Items.Clear();

      
        foreach (var i in allSalesReps)
        {
          
            if (i.GetType().Name == cboObjectType.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                lstSalesReps.Items.Add(i);
            }
            else if (i.GetType().BaseType.Name == cboObjectType.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                lstSalesReps.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

[Form Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdn9D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that shows `object` in combobox is this:

```
string baseType = thisSalesRep.GetType().BaseType.Name;
```

The base type of `SalesRep` is `object`. You should either remove `object` from your collection or never add in the first place.

`GetType` gives you the runtime type of the object. So I don't think you need `.BaseType`. Try this:

```cs
 public void LoadTypeComboBox()
    {
        List<string> salesRepTypes = new List<string>();
        
        foreach (SalesRep thisSalesRep in allSalesReps)
        {
            string type = thisSalesRep.GetType().Name;

            if (!salesRepTypes.Contains(s))
            {
                salesRepTypes.Add(s);
            }
        }

        cboObjectType.DataSource = salesRepTypes;
    }
```

Or even better with Linq:

```cs
cboObjectType.DataSource = allSalesReps
                    .Select(r => r.GetType().Name)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: @ToriPerkins You can mark it as accepted answer if it helped your problem :)